# What counts towards 100% in Red Dead Redemption?

Tags: ps3, red-dead-redemption

I played the whole game and I'm at 79%. But I can't find anything else to do, what counts to 100% completion? I found all the places, there aren't any side missions that I'm aware. I'm stuck and I'm not sure what else to do. Well, I haven't completed all the challenges in the game, but, I don't think that's the only thing I'm missing.

Comment: Do you have saves before the ending?

Comment: @Brok3n No, I don´t but for what i read, there is no missable missions in the game. Just "I know you?" or something like that, and I alredy finish that one. Why do you mention it?

Comment: @Zarathustrax "I know you" is not required for 100% as it is missable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rockstar used to have a [web checklist](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/rdr/checklist.html) for this, but it appears to be taken down. Anyway, 100% requires all:

1. Story missions (57)
2. Outfits (9)
3. Rare weapons purchased (5)
4. Houses owned (the two you can 'rent' do not count, 13)
5. Gang hideouts (7, the exclusive PS3 hideout does not count)
6. Challenges done (10 for sharpshooter, survival, hunting each, but 9 for treasure hunter)
7. Named bounties (8 in Mexico, 8 in New Austin, 4 in West Elizabeth)
8. Stranger tasks (19, note that these CAN be completed post-game)
9. "Win" at every minigame (generally, break even or better)
10. Map locations (you can buy maps at general stores)

That should cover everything for 100%. For more in-depth information, I recommend the following [GameFAQs guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/957922-red-dead-redemption/faqs/60077):